# Loading Storyboard From Documents Folder

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard that I want to load into my app at runtime, rather than at compile time.

If this was possible, I assume that I would load it into the app Documents folder; and then read it in with:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "TEST.storyboard", bundle: bundle);
```

I've tried playing around with the path; and whether or not I put the file in a bundle; but haven't gotten anywhere.

**Is this actually possible; or is iOS locked down to prevent it?**

Comment: No you can't add anything that needs to be compiled to an iOS app after its been built. And second, the documents directory is not part of the application bundle, that sits on the phone.